# Does the word "former" as in "former employee" shed negative light on the subject?

Tags: word-choice, tone

Does writing,

> Former technologist at Foobar, Inc. and Hello, World Ltd.

have a deprecating tone to it? Say, as opposed to,

> Previously a technologist at Foobar, Inc. and Hello, World Ltd.

That is, is *former* a word reserved for describing something (a state or position) once held but then revoked? It seems more *often* used in such a light, but I'm not sure whether it's *meant* that way.

Comment: Former telegrapher, Andrew Carnegie ... // Former millionaire, Burt Reynolds ...

Comment: The word has no negative connotations as far as I see it. It means 'used to be, but is no longer'. Former president, former singer with the band etc

Comment: I don't see how one can deduce a bad/wrong/false impression just by 'former'. It doesn't convey anything negative to me. Just a fact stated out.

Comment: @camelbrush - I did not mean by deduction that a word would mean something it does not; but because words sometimes gain or lose connotations over time, I wasn't sure if "former" gained a negative connotation, as I've heard the term used more oft than not to describe chairmen who were found committing fraud, or commnity leaders who had passed away, and such. It seems this is personal experience though, not shared by others: that's what I sought to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Former* does not indicate or imply that the position was revoked, removed, withdrawn, or in any way terminated for any negative reason. It merely means it was, but is no more. This could be for many reasons, so no particular reason can be inferred.

(Also, self-deprecating means that a person is referring to himself or herself in a deprecating way. You don't really mean to say *self*-deprecating; you mean to ask whether the term *former* in and of itself is deprecating no matter who says it.)

Comment: Thanks! (For the correction on _self-deprecating_, too; edited.)